# How to access model parameters (conditional probability table) of naive bayes in sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

We know that naive bayes model learns its parameters which are conditional probability tables from data.  I'm trying to find out how to access such tables in sklearn.  May I have your suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the conditional log probability and count of occurrence for each (feature, class).

Example based on the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB):

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.randint(2, size=(6, 10))
Y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2])
X

#array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
clf = BernoulliNB()
clf.fit(X, Y)

clf.feature_count_
#
array([[2., 2., 4., 1., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 1.],
       [2., 1., 1., 2., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.]])

clf.feature_log_prob_
#
array([[-0.69314718, -0.69314718, -0.18232156, -1.09861229, -0.69314718,
        -0.69314718, -1.09861229, -0.69314718, -0.69314718, -1.09861229],
       [-0.28768207, -0.69314718, -0.69314718, -0.28768207, -1.38629436,
        -0.69314718, -0.69314718, -1.38629436, -1.38629436, -0.69314718]])
```